# Google Analytic view conversation rate against sessions

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to find out how can i compare the conversion rate against the number of sessions for example how many people came to the specific page and bought that product.

In Google Analytic if I goto `Reporting->Conversions->E-commerce->Overview` I can see the overall conversion rate. But I want to see

1. How many people visited the site and how many out of them bought the product.
2. I want to see the above point stats against specific product/page too

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to Acquisition -> All traffic -> Channels. Then, above the Explorer graph, select "E-commerce" tab.

[image: Google Analaytics, Ecommerce overview by channel]

You can now go more in deep and see Revenue by pages. Use filters for selecting a specific page, or add Session as secondary dimension by the beginning and filter it out.

Or just use secondary dimensions by Page or Page Title in your Conversions-> Ecommerce reports.

[image: Secondary Dimensions by Landing page in Ecommerce tracking]

Also, Custom Reports.

[image: E-commerce custom report Analytics]

Yes, you can also use Goals. It's a good idea for tracking behavior more in general (so, see where people converts), but you need to use "average value" for a conversion. It's good for having focus on the "action" of conversion itself.

(last 2 screenshots are not mine, I'm not following E-commerce websites at the moment).

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, I will have a look and get back

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a [Goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en&ref_topic=6150889). Track the specific page you want, and set destination for product success. You can see the conversion of how many products were sold / how many people visited the page.